# Getting server side javascript over client side

Tags: asp.net, javascript

I have created custom control using asp.net 2.0. The control contains a textbox txtDate. I have also created a javascript file DateMask.js which contains a function maskDate(). I have attached the maskDate() with textbox using -

txtDate.Attributes.Add("onkeypress","maskDate()");

I have also registered the script using ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript.

When I execute the aspx page containing my custom control it is generating script error showing that maskDate() is undefined.

Could anybody tell me what exactly the problem is?

Thanks for your cooperation.

Comment: You didn't mention how you are including `DateMask.js`.

Comment: Where you have defined maskDate() function?

Comment: As a rule of thumb, when you are generating code form code (in this case JS from whatever language you are using in your ASP.NET) — the easiest way to debug is usually to start at the end and work backwards. What does the generated page look like? Is the function defined in the page? Is it defined in time? Is the onkeypress attribute correctly generated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it would be to place a literal control above your textbox, and assign the script to it in the code behind:

```
literal1.Text = "<script>function maskDate() {...}</script>";
```

The benefit to this, is you would not need to have to reference the script file with some tricky relative paths depending on where your usercontrol is used.

Comment: Thanks Josh! Thats a nice idea.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you didn't forget `<form runat="server" ID="Form1"></form>` at the end of the `<head>` tag!

As you can read in [Using JavaScript Along with ASP.NET 2.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479390.aspx) under "The Difference Between Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript  and Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock" they rely on the location of the form tag.

> We have shown two different methods
>   for placing JavaScript functions on an
>   ASP.NET page—so what is the
>   difference? The main difference is
>   that the RegisterStartupScript method
>   places the JavaScript at the bottom of
>   the ASP.NET page right before the
>   closing  element. The
>   RegisterClientScriptBlock method
>   places the JavaScript directly after
>   the opening  element in the
>   page. So what difference does this
>   make? It can make quite a bit of
>   difference, as we will see.

Comment: I know that ASP.NET can be weird — but would that really fix the problem of forms not being allowed inside the head element?